# Android performance meter

Tags: android, performance

I looking a tools that can be helps for me to measure my performance in some parts of code in my android application.

Is there any tools for help me?

Now i was written a class that measure my functions in app, but may be is exist more effective methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there are tools for that. Try this: [Android Systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html).

Comment: Actually i want to know what the execution time of my method.

Comment: You get everything with Systrace. It can analyze the execution time of single methods and also analyzes the execution times of all calls that are made in this method.

Comment: Please add more information about this tool or step-by-step tutorial and i will accept your answer.

Comment: Just look at the link I posted in my answer. There is a step-by-step instruction with a code example on how to use Systrace.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are looking for a tool to instrument your code and review your stack trace execution time or something more related to different metrics, but maybe I can help. I'm working on a tool we will release soon, this tool will allow us to monitor our application performance in production using real-time stats. The platform is named FlowUp http://flowup.io/. Just adding an Android library to your project you could monitor your application in production in real-time :)

Using FLowUp you can get information about your application performance in terms of:

- Frame time.
- Frames per second.
- Network consumption.
- CPU usage.
- Disk usage.
- Memory consumption in terms of load and bytes allocated.

And much more metrics. Of course, all these metrics can be reviewed crossing this information with some tags related to the application or the device. For example, you could get information about the network consumption or the frames per second of your app per activity and comparing different app or Android OS version.

This is an screenshot I've taken from our landing page:

[image: FlowUpScreenshot]

Right now we are under development but I recommend you to subscribe to our mail list in http://flowup.io to have access to the first beta we will release soon :)

If you have any metric you'd really like to monitor, please don't hesitate to request it! Maybe we can implement this for you :)